# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Employer without an ID) while using form Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

I checked various solutions that are available, but none seem to address the issue that I am having with my project. I am trying to allow the user to create reviews through the `EmployerReview` model for the employer. When I pass the `employer_id` to the `form_for` in the `employer_reviews_controller` it claims that it cannot find an employer without an ID. The id is being passed with the `@employer` instance variable. I don't get why it's not working. Lastly, I am using `friendly_id`, and it shows at the end of the new employer review address **employer_reviews/new.bryers**. How can I stop this error from occurring?

**schema**

```
create_table "employer_reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "review_body"
    t.string "review_title"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "employer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["employer_id"], name: "index_employer_reviews_on_employer_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_employer_reviews_on_user_id"
  end
```

**employer_review.rb**

```
class EmployerReview < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employer
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employer_reviews, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**employer.rb**

```
class Employer < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: [:slugged, :finders]
  has_many :employer_reviews, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**employers_controller.rb**

```
class EmployersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_employer, only: [:show]

  def show
    impressionist(@employer)
  end


  private

  def set_employer
    @employer = Employer.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**employer_reviews_controller.rb**

```
class EmployerReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_employer_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_employer
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /employer_reviews/1
  # GET /employer_reviews/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /employer_reviews/new
  def new
    @employer_review = EmployerReview.new
  end

  # GET /employer_reviews/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /employer_reviews
  # POST /employer_reviews.json
  def create
    @employer_review = EmployerReview.new(employer_review_params)
    @employer_review.user_id = current_user.id
    @employer_review.employer_id = @employer_review.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @employer_review.save
        format.html {redirect_to @employer_review, notice: 'Employer review was successfully created.'}
        format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: @employer_review}
      else
        format.html {render :new}
        format.json {render json: @employer_review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /employer_reviews/1
  # PATCH/PUT /employer_reviews/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employer_review.update(employer_review_params)
        format.html {redirect_to @employer_review, notice: 'Employer review was successfully updated.'}
        format.json {render :show, status: :ok, location: @employer_review}
      else
        format.html {render :edit}
        format.json {render json: @employer_review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /employer_reviews/1
  # DELETE /employer_reviews/1.json
  def destroy
    @employer_review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to employer_reviews_url, notice: 'Employer review was successfully destroyed.'}
      format.json {head :no_content}
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_employer_review
    @employer_review = EmployerReview.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_employer
    @employer = Employer.find(params[:employer_id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def employer_review_params
    params.require(:employer_review).permit([:review_title, :review_body])
  end
end
```

**employer show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Write a review', new_employer_review_path(@employer) %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :employers
resources :employer_reviews
```

**review form**

```
<%= simple_form_for([@employer, @employer_review]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Review Title</label>
    <%= f.input :review_title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Add a review title' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Tell us about your experience</label>
    <%= f.input :review_body, :as => :text, :input_html => { 'rows' => 5, 'cols' => 10 }, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Add a review title' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE 1:
I'm receiving the error below when I use both @employer_review and @employer in the simple_form.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <%= simple_form_for([@employer_review, @employer]) do |f| %>
    2:   <%= f.error_notification %>
    3:   <div class="form-group">
    4:     <label>Review Title</label>

app/views/employer_reviews/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_employer_reviews__form_html_erb__154747394_155744960'
app/views/employer_reviews/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_employer_reviews_new_html_erb__376973310_155859880'
Processing by ExceptionHandler::ExceptionsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"employer_id"=>"test_employer"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 404ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: I think `@employer_review.employer_id = @employer_review.id` in `EmployerReviewsController#create`  is a bug

Answer (score 3):

Your `employers` and `employer_reviews` resources are not nested. It means `employer_id` param in your `EmployerReviewsController` is `nil` (if it is not set explicitly in query string). Calling `set_employer` filter has no effect and `@employer` instance variable is `nil`. That's why `simple_form` cannot find that employer (without id).

You either have to turn `employer_reviews` to [nested resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) of `employers`, or remove `@employer` variable from `EmployerReviewsController` and use `simple_form` solely for `@employer_review`.

Comment: Controllers should be separate for sure. Currently your controllers are ok. Just change routing.

Comment: I tried your approach and made some progress. The issue that I'm having now, is the the validation is showing blank and returning back to the new action. Which probably means one of the model ids are not saving to the form before insertion. I tried to create the record inside of the console and it worked without issue. The employer_id is not <%= link_to "Review Company", new_employer_employer_review_path(@employer), class: 'bttn-bordered bttn-md bttn-royal' %> is not storing the employer_id. What can I do to get the value to store before the form commits?

Comment: I removed the @employer variable from the form as you asked. Now its just <%= simple_form_for(@employer_review) %> What do I do next?

Comment: For the employer_review migration. Its set to t.references :user and t.references :employer. Both should be available by default to the form. That's most likely why its not working correctly. I need to get a reference id from employers.

Comment: Let's go to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182392/room-for-ilya-konyukhov-and-cole-phiper)